# Error: Should not import the named export... at @atlaskit/editor-core

Tags: node.js, reactjs, atlaskit

I'm trying to use `@atlaskit/editor-core` for the first time.
I installed it with `npm i @atlaskit/editor-core`, my npm version is `8.3.0` and my node version is `16.13.1`.

However, when I try to run my app, I get many errors with the same pattern:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/esm/plugins/feedback-dialog/index.js 95:183-1
Should not import the named export 'version' (imported as 'coreVersion') from default-exporting lt export is available soon)
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@atlaskit/status/dist/esm/components/analytics.js 53:43-54
Should not import the named export 'name' (imported as 'packageName') from default-exporting module (only default 
export is available soon)
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@atlaskit/analytics-listeners/dist/esm/atlaskit/process-event.js 97:21-3
Should not import the named export 'version' (imported as 'listenerVersion') from default-exportefault export is available soon)
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@atlaskit/editor-common/dist/esm/ui/LegacyToNextIntlProvider/index.js 11
export 'intlShape' (imported as 'intlShape') was not found in 'react-intl'
```

and others similar.

My package.json contains these dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@atlaskit/editor-core": "^153.1.3",
        "@atlaskit/media-core": "^32.2.0",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.5",
        "@mui/material": "^5.2.7",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "emoji-picker-react": "^3.5.0",
        "firebase": "^9.6.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-google-button": "^0.7.2",
        "react-intl": "^5.24.2",
        "react-mde": "^11.5.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
        "redux": "^4.1.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
        "sass": "^1.47.0",
        "showdown": "^1.9.1",
        "simplemde": "^1.11.2",
        "styled-components": "^3.2",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
        "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-core": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-routing": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-streams": "^5.1.4"
    },
```

---

I saw around that some people recommend including `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` on `tsconfig.json`, however, I had not this file because I'm not using Typescript.
So I added Typescript and that line, but all errors persist.

---

As this is an error inside the node_module folder I don't believe editing the package will work

---

I also tried to create other react project to test this with no changes after

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
yarn add @atlaskit/editor-core

// Add on index.js 
// - import { Editor } from "@atlaskit/editor-core";
// - <Editor appearance="comment" />;

yarn start
```

But unluckily, this gave me the same errors.

---

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has the same problem with atlaskit, I asked [here](https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/error-should-not-import-the-named-export-in-editor-core/55083) too, and looks like this is a dependency problem.

To solve it for me, I downgraded some packages to match this configuration:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@atlaskit/editor-core": "^151.3.0",
    "@atlaskit/media-core": "^32.2.0",
    "@atlaskit/renderer": "^81.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-intl": "2.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.6"
  }
```

As Ryker Tyler said on the other forum:

> According to my experience with Atlaskit, it has a huge dependence on the version of react, react-scripts, webpack and also its own peer dependencies (between @atlaskit/editor-core and @atlaskit/media-core for example, and it also requires peer dependencies on react-intl and styled-components on the specific version.

> Some Atlaskit components are not yet compatible with React 17 and react-scripts 5.x.x. They are still dependent on React 16 and react-scripts 4.x.x.

> I think you could try to downgrade to React 16 and react-scripts 4 if you want to work well with Atlaskit.

Comment: Excellent, have you tried upgrading to the latest version? I copy and paste your depedencies but still get the same error you had above. Maybe you changed something else to get it working?